# Cache SELECT query using Doctrine Entity Manager

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I use Doctrine Entity Manager in my code several times, I used in this way for example:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$countries = $em->getRepository('CommonBundle:Country')->findAll();
```

It's possible to use Doctrine Cache in this format? I see a lot of docs but all of them relative to Doctrine Query Builder, any advice? How to enable cache for `SELECT` queries?

**Caching is not working (tough)**

I'm dealing with caching results and I do this in order to cache some queries:

- Enable APC under `orm` configuration at `config.yml`:

  ```
  doctrine:
      dbal:
          driver:   "%database_driver%"
          host:     "%database_host%"
          port:     "%database_port%"
          dbname:   "%database_name%"
          user:     "%database_user%"
          password: "%database_password%"
          charset:  UTF8
      orm:
          auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
          auto_mapping: true
          metadata_cache_driver: apc
          result_cache_driver: apc
          query_cache_driver: apc
  ```
- Attach a repository to my entity:

  ```
  /**
   * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CommonBundle\Entity\Repository\CountryRepository")
   */
  class Country {
      ....
  ```
- Write a method inside repository class for get the data and cache the results:

  ```
  public function getCountries() {
      $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
      $query = $qb->getQuery();
      $query->useResultCache(true, 3600, 'countries_cache');
      return $query->getResult();
  }
  ```

But any time I reload the page the query is executed as shown in the profiler (see picture below):

[image]

What I did wrong? The cache only works for production or also works for development? Should't get cached results instead of query the database once and once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EntityRepository API does NOT allow to enable ResultCache with find* methods.

You have to use a QueryBuilder and/or DQL requests.

I wrote an article about Doctrine caching, maybe it can help you : http://blog.alterphp.com/2014/05/doctrine2-optimization-with-apc-cache.html

Comment: Can you take a look to my edition? Something is not working on my steps or I miss something

Comment: I'm not sure toolbar is trustable to test caching, maynbe it does not hide cached queries... You should change data in DB between 2 requests to test caching.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable cache for results in your symfony configuration :

```
doctrine:
    orm:        
        metadata_cache_driver: apc # or memcache
        result_cache_driver: apc   # or memcache
        query_cache_driver: apc    # or memcache
```

Then on every request that need to be cached, call

`$query->useResultCache(true)`

More advanced options available here : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/caching.html#result-cache